# How to randomly access a file in a zip file in an efficient way?

Tags: java, jar, io

I want to parse a large file in a zip file. Parsing the file requires random access to it. In a word, the procedure is to read a header first, get some offsets from the header, and then seek to the offsets to read the real data. The actual structure is much more complex, so it's almost impossible to avoid random access.

The file isn't too large to fit in a `byte[]`, but since it is still quite large (around 50M), and I may have to deal with many files like this at a time, I don't want to simply read all the bytes of it into a `byte[]`. I don't want to extract the whole file, then open it with `RandomAccessFile` either, due to performance overhead.

Here's basically what I want:

```java
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // In a zip file, unable to use RandomAccessFile
        var url = new URL("jar:file:/C:/path/to/jar/foo.zip!/foo/bar/large.dat");
        try (var stream = ?) {  // How to do this?
            // I can do something like...
            stream.seek(42);
            stream.read();
            stream.tell();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me a way to get random access the file in an efficient way, please? Thanks.

Comment: You can't do random access without extracting the file first (at least the entry you're interested in; not necessarily the entire zip).

Comment: You can *in theory* do random access to a file inside of a ZIP file **if and only if** the file isn't compressed (i.e. stored as-is inside the zip), but I don't think the standard Java APIs provide a way to do this, you might have to go to some third-party ZIP library for this kind of access and depending on your requirements that may or may not be worth the hassle.

Comment: Unless you need to read some of the data to find where to seek the next data item, you may be able to do this in a serial read without storing the entire thing in memory. If you can read the header from the start and deduce the offsets and length of all the data, order the list of offsets in ascending order then skip and read, skip and read.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, as the file format is weird (a proprietary format), I even have to seek to the end of the file to read some metadata, and then seek back, @RealSkeptic 's method doesn't work for me :( As @Oliver said, random access isn't possible without extracting the file first, so maybe I will just extract the whole file into a `byte[]`.